Bending of vacuum level in pn junction
The vacuum energy level is the same for both an isolated p-type and n-type materials means that the absolute energy of an electron that is just outside the p type material is the same as the absolute energy of an electron that is just outside the n type material.
When both isolated p-type and n-type materials join together and form pn-junction, the vacuum energy level also bend so it is higher on the the p-side than on the n-side. I want to confirm it means that the absolute energy of an electron that is just outside the material on the p-side higher than the absolute energy of an electron that is just outside the material on the n-side?
Reference image:


Well, yes, an electron on the P side is at a higher potential energy level.
But, this is a consequence of thermodynamics, not a 'free promotion'
to higher energy.   The step in voltage at a PN junction is a
consequence of diffusion of charge carriers, and the average electron
energy (potential and kinetic combined) has the same value on
both sides of the junction.
At absolute zero temperature, there's no step; there's no excess
kinetic energy to spare.   At finite temperature, that isn't the
case.

When you have a junction of 2 different crystals their Fermi level must be the same and it makes sense since they are connected to each other the Fermi energy must be the same.The energy bands dont need to be in the same energy.
The equillibrium is reached by diffusion of majority carriers of one side of the junction to the other side of the junction.
